# Is there a reliable way to send an IQueryable to a remote server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-2.1

I have an IQueryable instance, for example:

```
var query = context.Users.AsQueryable()
    .Where(u => u.DisplayName.StartsWith("J"))
    .OrderBy(u => u.LastLogin);
```

`context` is a client-side context using a local SQLite database.

I want to somehow send this object to an ASP.NET Core WebAPI running on a remote server, and execute the query on the server-side database (which is using the same models).

Is there a way to do this?

Translation to SQL would probably be an option, but I question the reliability, as I would have to manually provide an instance of the remote database provider (as far as I understand) so the resulting query is actually valid there.

What are my options here?

Comment: Having the server accept either the `IQueryable` or SQL comes with considerable *risks*. Are you sure it's safe to even do this? If not, I'd strongly suggest a small DSL based on e.g. JSON - `{"filters": [{"column":"displayName", "operator":"startswith","value":"J"}], "sort": [{"column":"lastLogin", "direction":"asc"}]}`. Then your server can reject anything it doesn't like or that will cause resource starvation, rather than blindly doing what the client said to.

Comment: @Follpvosten  You are probably looking for [OData](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2018/07/03/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/), which can already work with ASP.NET Core and EF Core.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serialize.Linq/ should be the answer

Comment: @Follpvosten are you SURE you want this feature though? Why do you want it in the first place? There's a reason Google abandoned its own GData, OData hasn't caught up despite great support and requiring minimal developer effort and GraphQL doesn't allow you to specify operators. The *data model* is seldom a good candidate for a REST/HTTP.

Comment: `IQueryable` means that the object can be queried for info later, If you could send the object to the server, without any callback system, there would be no way to effectively query the object. Check other comments for alternatives

Comment: @Follpvosten if you want to put an HTTP API in front of the database "because it's better" it isn't. It's actually far, far worse. You move from a binary to a verbosetext format thus using a LOT more bandwidth. You lose security and can't stream data as they are returned from the database, lose true async database operations, lose transactions. Having a middle tier handle business logic makes sense. Sticking an HTTP API in front of the database with no additional functionality only creates problems

Comment: You can have a database access service, arguments for a generic method would be: `string connectionStringName, string tableName, string serializedLamda`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was doing it that way in an older version of my product. I just thought I could maybe avoid unecessary classes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't fully understand what odata is for, but it doesn't look like there is a library for translating local LINQ queries to it, or is there?
The reason for wanting an HTTP API here is rather complicated; I will describe it in the next comment.

Comment: @SilentTremor I've tried that, it throws an exception when I try to serialize query.Expression.

Comment: @Follpvosten you don't need to translate the LINQ query. OData *does* provide that feature anyway - the OData client offers a full LINQ interface genearated from the HTTP API's schema.. Support is built into ASP.NET Core as the article shows

Comment: @Follpvosten it's not even a *new* feature, it's available on top of EF for about 7 years. There's even a project template for it in VS

Comment: So, I have a .NET Standard library that doubles as a local (Xamarin.Forms), and a website (ASP.NET (Core)) backend.
When a request comes in, depending on the type of request and where it's currently running (server mode or local mode), it either writes directly to the local database or sends a request to the database service (which provides only database sync when in local mode).

However, I just realized that with EF, I could just switch my database provider based on where the software is running, providing all of the benefits I want.

Thanks for the hints!